# Login in Grafana by API

Tags: http, https, grafana

I’m trying to develop a web site with buttons that, when clicked, redirect the user to a Grafana Dashboard. If I redirect directly to the link, it opens a login page. I want to skip this step and do this automatically on my backend with an API login when the button is clicked.

How can I achieve this? The service is on our server.